# supplying parameters to $resource

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have

```
angular.factory('Service', [
  '$resource', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('/path/:id', {id: '@id'});
  }])
```

If in my controller I do

```
var s = new Service({id: 123});
s.$query();
```

it sends a request to `/path`, but I expected it to send a request to `/path/123`. Why does it do that and how to set the parameter?

I do not want to provide any parameters to `$query()`. I want to set the "default" ones. The one denoted by `@id`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312162/customizing-angularjs-resource-default-parameters-in-a-service

Answer (score 1):

`$query` is used to get a list of records. What you want is `$get`

```
var s = Service.get({id :123}, function optionalFn(){});
```

See more [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: this is not what I am asking

Comment: Are you sure? `s` will be an empty object but when the xhr finish it will be update to the record. If you need to play with it when xhr finish `optionalFn` is what you need. Why this isn't what you asked?

Comment: I am asking how to set up a property and where so that it gets picked up by the @-rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think the example controller here is actually sending the id parameter to the factory itself, which the factory doesn't need. With the way this is set up, you would need to send a parameter inside query() or you would have the option of changing the resource path id value inside the factory code from '@id' to 123. I believe '@id' is telling it to look for the id parameter in a call like query({id:123}).